# how to add sdk version in a react native project already created?

Tags: android, react-native, sdk, android-version, android-api-levels

I created a project a month ago and I'm working on, I want to know:

1. which sdk version is in my project
2. how to add other previous version as lollipop (API 21),
   marshmallow (API 23), nougat (API 24),  oreo (API 26)...
3. if it's possible to add theme, should I change something in my
   components code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to `android/app/build.gradle` find out the `compileSdkVersion,buildToolsVersion` part it's the sdk version you compiling with.
2. If your `minSdkVersion` is 16 then it will run on the previous versions.
3. It's possible to add theme if you need to add the native part. Here is the official [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android)

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I did not understand what is in this part:
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

version 1_8 means that i use version 18 ? so I cant add 15, 16, 17 versions ?

Comment: No, it's means your jdk version. And check your minSdkVersion. The formula is

minSdkVersion <= targetSdkVersion <= compileSdkVersion

Comment: I find this in a rootProjet, build.gradle in my root project:
__    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Your project will support between sdk 16  to 28